# Tags or Nested Sets for Category / Sub-Category Items

Tags: php, database, database-design

Tags

```
create table product (id, name,...)
create table tag (id, name, description)
create table product_tag (product_id, tag_id)
```

NESTED SETS ?

Requirement
Probably will hit 200 000 rows of products.
300-500 Tags(Category & Sub Category)

Question
Is Tag good enough? A product would most probably have 5 Tags?  Or do i really have to use Nested Sets

Answer (score 1):

How about an array of tags? Modern databases support array of characters like `char[]`.
And you can easily query this array for great performance.